# Selenium Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Tags: html, selenium, jenkins

I have a page like this:

```html
<div class="CodeMirror">
<div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 3px; height: 0px; top: 6.2px; left: 182.2px;">
 <textarea autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" style="position: absolute; padding: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1em;" wrap="off"></textarea>
</div>
<div style="display: none; height: 106px;" class="CodeMirror-scrollbar">   <div style="height: 114px;" class="CodeMirror-scrollbar-inner"></div></div>
<div> ...
...
..
</div>
<pre style="top: 39px; left: 0px;" class="CodeMirror-cursor">&nbsp;</pre>
<div style="">
<pre>asdf</pre>
<pre>asdfasdf</pre> It's weird the textarea content is here
<pre>asdfasdf</pre>
<pre> </pre>
</div>
...
...
```

and I use selenium to select, but get two elements and I send key to one of them it throws `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with`

Here is my operation command:

```html
browser.browser.public_send(:textareas, :xpath => "//div[@class='CodeMirror']//textarea[@wrap='off']" )[0].html
=> "<textarea autocapitalize=\"off\" autocorrect=\"off\" style=\"position: absolute; padding: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1em;\" wrap=\"off\"></textarea>"
[58] pry(#<CucuShift::DefaultWorld>)> browser.browser.public_send(:textareas, :xpath => "//div[@class='CodeMirror']//textarea[@wrap='off']" )[1].html
=> "<textarea autocapitalize=\"off\" autocorrect=\"off\" style=\"position: absolute; padding: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1em;\" wrap=\"off\"></textarea>"

browser.browser.public_send(:textareas, :xpath => "//div[@class='CodeMirror']/descendant::textarea[@autocorrect='off']" )[1].click

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
from [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20160801-26332-bu7605/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:10092:in `fxdriver.preconditions.visible'

browser.browser.public_send(:textareas, :xpath => "//div[@class='CodeMirror']/descendant::textarea[@autocorrect='off']" )[1].send_keys '1234'

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
from [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20160801-26332-bu7605/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:10092:in `fxdriver.preconditions.visible'
```

the most weird thing is those too elements html are same.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are not able to access the textarea is that the parent div of your textarea has the attribute "overflow: hidden".
Hence, your textarea is invisible. If you delete the "overflow:hidden" attribute from your code, the textarea will be visible and you'll be able to access it with Selenium -and manually.

Note to reviewers: in fact, the question itself is not that clear. I tried to answer it relying on the title: the user wants to interact with a web element, and my answer provides a solution.

Comment: Actually, It's CodeMirror's problem